# Angular Session Issue

Tags: javascript, angular

suppose I am on the home page or any page of application if I want to open any page like google from the same tab then i will remove current URL and type google.com then it will go to google page and if i click on browser back button 
it will not go to home page of my application which is already login so it should go to the login page of my application in angular js

Comment: you must, make a lgin validation, and force to redirect to home if is loged, and prevent to show again login ;)

Answer (score 0):

On your login page you should check if the user is already logged in. If the user is already logged in, redirect the user to where you want them to be.

An other option is to check before changing routes. If the user is logged in and wants to go to the login page, you can deny that route change. (check  $routeChangeStart in the [angular $route documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route))